# Python ElementTree Check the node / element type

Tags: python, elementtree

I am using ElementTree and cannot figure out if the childnode is text or not. `childelement.text` does not seem to work as it gives false positive even on nodes which are not text nodes.

Any suggestions?

*Example*

```
<tr>
  <td><a href="sdas3">something for link</a></td>
  <td>tttttk</td>
  <td><a href="tyty">tyt for link</a></td>
</tr>
```

After parsing this xml file, I do this in Python:

```
for elem_main in container_trs: #elem_main is each tr
    elem0 = elem_main.getchildren()[0] #td[0]
    elem1 = elem_main.getchildren()[1] #td[1]

    elem0 = elem_main.getchildren()[0]
    print elem0.text

    elem1 = elem_main.getchildren()[1]
    print elem1.text
```

The above code does not output elem0.text; it is blank. I do see the elem1.text (that is, *tttttk*) in the output.

**Update 2**

I am actually building a dictionary. The text from the element with each  so that I can sort the HTML table. How would I get the s in this code?

Comment: @Justin. Please check the example.

Comment: You have confused me :). Please rephrase the last two paragraphs.

Comment: @Rahul I agree. lol changed the text and code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `getiterator` method to iterate through the all the descendant nodes:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xee

content='''
<tr>
  <td><a href="sdas3">something for link</a></td>
  <td>tttttk</td>
  <td><a href="tyty">tyt for link</a></td>
</tr>
'''

def text_content(node):
    result=[]
    for elem in node.getiterator():
        text=elem.text
        if text and text.strip():
            result.append(text)
    return result

container_trs=xee.fromstring(content)
adict={}
for elem in container_trs:
    adict[elem]=text_content(elem)
print(adict)
# {<Element td at b767e52c>: ['tttttk'], <Element td at b767e58c>: ['tyt for link'], <Element td at b767e36c>: ['something for link']}
```

The loop  `for elem_main in container_trs:` iterates through the children of `cantainer_trs`.

In contrast, the loop `for elem_main in container_trs.getiterator():` iteraters through `container_trs` itself, and its children, and grand-children, etc.

Comment: I am actually building a dictionary. The text from the element with each `<tr>` so that I can sort the HTML table. How would I get the `<tr>`s in this code?

Comment: @AJ: I've changed the code a bit to show how you could grab all the text below each `td` node.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it tomorrow and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

`elem0.text` is None because the text is actually part of the <a> subelement. Just go one level deeper:

```
print elem0.getchildren()[0].text
```

By the way, `elem0[0].text` is a shortcut for that same construct -- no need for getchildren().

Comment: I know this. I just want to know how to check whether I need to go one level deeper?